# Delete, add and display data swift table view controller

Tags: swift, realm

Im my Swift app, I need to display data in a tableview. The data at server side changes often, and therefore I need to delete any previous data and add the new data fetched. I am able to delete and fetch and I can see the new data in the console as well as realm browser. However, the data is not available in the table view controller from Results.

```
class ServiceProvidersTableViewController: UITableViewController {    
    // MARK: - Data Source
    var serviceSubCategory: String = ""
    var serviceSubCategories: Results<ServiceSubCategory>?

    // MARK: - Realm
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let fetchData = FetchData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.deleteSubCategories()

        FetchData.get(ServiceSubCategory.self, params: ["subCategoryId": serviceSubCategory], success: {            
            self.infoAlert("Service Categories", message: "Fetch Successful")
        }) {
            self.infoAlert("Failed", message: "Fetch Failed")
        }
        self.fetchSubCategories()
    }

    func deleteSubCategories()
    {
        let subCategories = realm.objects(ServiceSubCategory.self)
        print("Before delete \(subCategories)")
        try! realm.write{
            realm.delete(subCategories)
        }
        print("After delete \(subCategories)")
    }

    func fetchSubCategories() {
        self.realm.refresh()
        self.serviceSubCategories = self.realm.objects(ServiceSubCategory)
        tableView.reloadData()
        print("After fetch \(self.serviceSubCategories)")
    }

    struct Storyboard {
        static let CellIndentifier = "ServiceProvidersCell"
    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        print(self.serviceSubCategories!.count)
        return self.serviceSubCategories!.count


    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Storyboard.CellIndentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ServiceProvidersTableViewCell
       print(serviceSubCategories)
        cell.serviceSubCategories = self.serviceSubCategories![indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func infoAlert(title:String,message:String) -> Void {
        let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title:title, message:message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in }
        actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: did you call `tableView.reloadData()` when your new results available?

Comment: yes, I am following the tutorial at https://blog.hyphe.me/realm-and-alamofire-in-a-effective-harmony/. How do I check new Results?

Comment: Did you set `delegate` & `dataSource` properties of `tableView`?

Comment: Yes, In viewDidLoad() I call a function with a try block and delete the object `func deleteObject(){let objectToDelete = realm.objects(object) try! realm.write{realm.delete(objectToDelete)}  }`

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: Next I add `func fetchObject() { self.objectName = self.realm.objects(object)}` self.objectName.count always returns zero

Comment: Please paste the complete code in your question, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved (I should say, I am dumb) as follows:-

The `FetchData` method has a callback `success`, which in the example I used displays an alert.

I created another function in the tableViewController and called this in the `success` call back. Inside the new method I called `self.tableView.reloadData()`.

Thanks to all for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to delete the object from the local "serviceSubCategory" and not just from the server.

Put a `tableView.reloadData()` everytime the server listener fires.

Probably in the `fetchSubCategories()` and `deleteSubCategories()` functions.

Comment: adding `tableView.reloadData()` to `fetchSubCategories()` has no effect and adding it to `deleteSubCategories()` throws `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` in `return self.serviceSubCategories!.count`

Comment: In the  function numberOfRowsInSection do this: if self.serviceSubCategories != nil { return self.servicesSubCategories.count } else { return 0 }

Comment: This always returns zero, though the data is being retrieved from server.

Comment: Well this is what you need to do: 1. Receive info from server 2. Store info locally 3. ReloadData. You just need to know where your data is stored and reloadData right after it